# Django - Ensure ordering of response data is newer first

Tags: python, django

So I have some code below that returns posts that are newer than a post with `post_uuid` given. This is ensured because I force an ordered uuid scheme where each `Post` is given a uuid in order of creation, this is done with ulid. I want to enforce that that the returned `serializer.data` is ordered by `Post` creation data, with the newest best first or index=0 and oldest being last. How do I ensure this?

`view.py`

```
def query_to_full_post_data_serializer(request, post_query_set: QuerySet):
    query_set_annotated = post_query_set.annotate(
        creator_username=F('creator__username'),
        creator_avatar_url=F('creator__avatar')
    )
    return FullPostDataSerializer(query_set_annotated, many=True)

@api_view(['GET'])
def get_newer_posts(request, post_uuid, count):
    query = generate_followee_or_join_goal_follow_query(request)
    query = query & Q(uuid__gt=post_uuid)
    serializer = query_to_full_post_data_serializer(request=request, post_query_set=Post.objects.filter(query).order_by('uuid')[:count])
    return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

`serializer.py`

```
class FullPostDataSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    creator_username = serializers.SlugField()
    creator_avatar_url = serializers.SlugField()

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = (
            'body', 'created', 'creator_username', 'uuid', 'creator', 'creator_avatar_url')
```

**Tried Solutions**

-

```
serializer.data.reverse()
```

doesn't reverse the list for some reason.

- tried to `order_by` on the slice, but this isn't allowed by Django

Comment: A `uuid` is a *random* identifier, this thus does *not* filters by creation time. Use `.order_by('-created')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `serializer.data` is a property, so calling `.reverse()` on it, will not work, since you reverse the result of the property, but the next call to `serializer.data` will again trigger to property that will construct a new list.

You thus fetch the data, and then reverse that data and pass it as result:

```
items = serializer.data
items.reverse()
return Response(items, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Comment: I actually enforce my uuids to be ordered by creation time

Comment: @user8714896: don't! That completely defeats the purpose of a UUID. The idea of a UUID is that any device can create these, and these are *quasi*-guaranteed to be unique and thus make it possible to merge from different devices.

Comment: to be explicit I use ulid to set my uuids. Is that still an issue?

Comment: the reason I do this is because my `Post` table can get updated very frequently so I need to be able to do a form of pagination with a table that grows very quickly. So if the user has posts id=[3,7] and they want posts with id 8 they can get 8 or higher. If they want newer posts. Lets say posts [0,2] just got created. They can get that by giving the id of 3 and ask for posts newer than id=3 or posts older than id=7

Comment: @user8714896: but your model has a `created` field, correct? Then you have a timestamp... One with up to microseconds precision.

Comment: I found in some cases for w.e I would get `Post` with the exact same creation time. Specifically when running tests. So I had tests for checking ordering and what not and that would break because Python's ordering of the response.data, which I used to compare wouldn't be exactly the same as what Django returned because their creation times were exactly the same.

Comment: @user8714896: what did you set as `default=...` in the `created`  field?

Comment: `created = models.DateTimeField('Created at', auto_now_add=True)`

Comment: @user8714896: well you can use `.order_by('-uuid')` I guess, still quite strange that these have the same timestamp. If you use `bulk_create`, then these will of course have the same timestamp, since these are written in the same transaction.

Comment: I don't use `bulk_create` I actually do `Post.objects.create()` in a for loop and it still has the same create time for w.e reason. One of my potential ways around it was put a timer between each iteration of the for loop, but I thought that unnecessarily slowed down test runtime.

Comment: you brought up some great points and seem to know a bit about Django any ideas on a solution to the original problem I posted?

Comment: @user8714896: does `.order_by('-uuid')[:count]` do the job? By prepending with a hyphen, you reverse the order.

Comment: So the issue with that solution is that it'll get you the `count` newest. But I want the `count` newest after the given `Post` uuid, which would be `.order_by('-uuid')[-count:]`. Unfortunately Django doesn't allow negative indexing.

Comment: @user8714896: how do you use `serializer.data.reverse()`?

Comment: I call it before I pass `serializer.data` to Response. Doesn't do anything unfortunately not really sure why it's just a list.

Comment: @user8714896: ah, but `.data` is a property, you thus should use a variable, see edited answer.

Comment: awesome. Sorry Django is being so annoying for me rn. Sometimes it'll have different creation dates then other times they'll all be the same. Is there a way to enforce different creation dates when creating test data?

Comment: @user8714896: yes, for tests you can make use of the [**`freezegun`**](https://github.com/spulec/freezegun) to "travel in time", and thus update the "wall clock" for testing purposes.

Comment: hmmm I can't tell if this is better than what I'm doing. It might be in my head the issue with both is parallel running gunicorn instances which is apparently how you handle the monolith issue with Django and tons of traffic. If you can truly enforce differing creation dates problem solved. ulid hopefully would still be fine with parallel guinicorn instances. Hmmm what are your thoughts?